# show modal after accepting cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I need to show the modal with youtube video after the click on the cookie banner, for accepting.
now, after this action, the page refresh and the video start correctly, but starts also the video into the modal box.

this is the code:

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 


        var id = '#dialog';

        //prendi dimensioni schermo
        var maskHeight = jQuery(document).height();
        var maskWidth = jQuery(window).width();


        //if (jQuery('#cc-approve-button-thissite').click(function(){
            //jQuery('#mask').css({'display', none});

            if (jQuery('#cc-notification').is(':visible')) {
                jQuery('#dialog').css({display: "none"});

            } else {

            jQuery('#boxes').css({display: "block"});

            //imposta altezza e larghezza maschera
            jQuery('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

            //transizione
            jQuery('#mask').fadeIn(500);    
            jQuery('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9); 

            //altezza - larghezza
            var winH = jQuery(window).height();
            var winW = jQuery(window).width();

            //vedi al centro
            jQuery(id).css('top',  winH/2-jQuery(id).height()/2);
            jQuery(id).css('left', winW/2-jQuery(id).width()/2);

            //transition
            jQuery(id).fadeIn(2000);    

            //al click su close
            jQuery('.window .close').click(function (e) {
            //Cancel the link behavior
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery('#mask').hide();
            jQuery('.window').hide();
            });

            //al click sulla maschera
            jQuery('#mask').click(function () {
            jQuery(this).hide();
            jQuery('.window').hide();
            });
            };  

        //});

});
```

HTML

```
    <div id="boxes">
        <div id="dialog" class="window">

                <iframe width="700" height="400" 
                src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/sTujqJHITDs?autoplay=1">
                </iframe>

          <div id="popupfoot"> <a href="#" class="close agree">Close</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="mask"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#mask {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
}

#boxes .window {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxes #dialog {
  width: 750px;
  height: 420px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

#popupfoot {
  font-size: 16pt;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

Comment: if you are setting cookie why not checking for cookie `if (!!$.cookie('accepted')) { /*hide modal*/ } else { /*show modal* }`

Comment: Create a new function and use onclick